# How to enable pcntl extensions in MAMP pro?

Tags: mamp, laravel-horizon

I am using laravel/horizon with Osx MAMP pro

when I run the composer it requires `laravel/horizon:~1.0`

it shows a message -

> laravel/horizon v1.0.8 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP
> extension pcntl is missing from your system.

I checked the folder `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php7.1.1/php/ext`,it doesn't contain pcntl extension.

How can I install that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. download php from http://www.php.net/releases/
2. `tar -xzvf php-7.2.1.tar.gz`
3. `cd php-7.2.1/ext/pcntl`
4. `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/phpize`
5. as @ drewjoh metioned `./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php-config --prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php`
6. `make && make install`
7. the terminal shows

`Installing shared extensions:     /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/`

8. open MAMP PRO menu->File ->Edit Template->PHP->7.2.1 add `extension=pcntl.so` at the end of the php.ini file .
9. run the command `php --ri pcntl` and shows
   `pcntl pcntl support => enabled`

Comment: WARNING!!! Make sure you did step 8.If you edit php.ini in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/conf/php.ini,it wont work. php -m show nothing.The only way is edit php.ini file in MAMP pro

Comment: I got this error when doing make: `/Users/ikkez/Downloads/php-7.3.8/ext/pcntl/pcntl.c:32:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found` ... any idea how to solve this?

Comment: For anyone hitting the `'php.h file not found` error... on Step 5, add `--with-php-config=` -- so it will look like: `./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php-config --prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php`

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition. Perhaps you followed the above step and still can't get it installed to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/`. Here is something I did that worked for me.

I added the `--with-php-config` before the `--prefix` flag and it worked. See step below.

1. download your MAMP php version from http://www.php.net/releases/ Mine is php7.2.22

Open your terminal and cd into your download folder. Then run this command to decompress the tar.gz file

```
tar -xzvf php-7.2.22.tar.gz
```

Cd into the pcntl directory after decompressing.

```
cd php-7.2.22/ext/pcntl
```

Run the next line from your terminal to Configure for PHP Api, Zend Module Api, and Zend Extension Api.

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.22/bin/phpize
```

Then run

```
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.22/bin/php-config --prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.22/bin/php; make && make install;
```

You should see

```
Installing shared extensions:     /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.22/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/
```

Then you can repeat the last two steps above.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the precompiled extensions from here https://github.com/khanakiaphp/mamp_extensions